# Polling oracle records from biztalk based using parameters

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a need to create a BizTalk 2010 application to poll information and I have found this useful blog [Polling Oracle Database Using Stored Procedures, Functions, or Packaged Procedures and Functions](http://pellitterisbiztalkblog.wordpress.com/2013/07/01/polling-oracle-database-using-stored-procedures-functions-or-packaged-procedures-and-functions/).

My questions are 2 folds:

1. The blog hard coded the parameter for the procedure in the package in the polledDataAvailable and the PolledStatement. How do I pass the actual parameters that is going to change? For example, I want to have the ability poll all orders from a customer, and not just the customer hard-coded 'ABC'. The ID of the customer will be defined at real time.
2. Without using extra receive ports but just based BizTalk monitor (referring back to the blog), how do I examine the results (i.e. viewing the records being polled) on BizTalk monitor?

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe the parameter value seems to be hard coded to call the function in the query statement SELECT CCM_ADT_PKG.CCM_COUNT('A02') FROM DUAL , but the real parameters values are passed to the generated instance from the input schema in the section "Modify XML content setting up the right parameters."
2. I don't know how your message result will be used, but if you use a send port to send the result somewhere, but you can create a simple FILE send port to store your message instance.